# regex : Parse a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

**Use case**

Prepare a regex which can match 1 or 2 words after 'sell|sold|selling' and matches the variable "product"

**Example**

```
Sentence - "John wants to sell 200$ XYZ laptop and buy ABC PC"

if product = "ABC" , then it should not match

If product = "XYZ" , then it should match
```

**What I did *(javascript)***

```
var desc = "John wants to sell 200$ XYZ laptop and buy ABC PC"
var product = "ABC"

var reg_s="sell\|selling\|sold (.*)" + product;
var re_s= new RegExp(reg_s,'gi');
var sell = desc.match(re_s);
```

> In the above code , the whole string after 'sell' is getting matched - but it should
>   not match for ABC. Need to match only those products which **appear 1,2 words
>   after sell|sold|selling**. For eg: product = XYZ should match

I am new to regex and learning the same. Need your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(.*)` segment in the regex will indeed match the rest of the string because `.` basically means any character. If you only want to get the next two "words", you need to limit the capture with something like:

```
(\S+)\s*(\S*)
```

This would give you two capture groups, one for each of the (up to) two words following the fixed string.

---

Further on that, I'd suggest using the following as a baseline:

```
var desc = "John wants to sell 200$ XYZ laptop and buy ABC PC";
var product = "ABC";

var reg_s="(sell|sold|selling)\\s+(\\S*\\s*\\S*)";
var re_s= new RegExp(reg_s,'gi');
var sell = re_s.exec(desc);
alert(sell[2]);
```

This gives you an actual array of captured groups whereas the array given to you by `string.match` will be an array of strings without the individual capture groups split up.

Comment: Thank you so much .. I will learn more and try to tweak for other regex .. Thanks :)